# Clarification required on responsibility of "$scope" in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

Clarification required on responsibility of `$scope` in AngularJS. Is it that `$scope` is recommended to be used only with the data and not with functions?

Which one is recommended ?

```
$scope.phoneNumbers = dirService.query();
```

or

```
$scope.getPhoneNumbers = function(){
....//logic to get the data. 
}
```

Comment: 1st one looks good, as it does handled separation of concern in better way..as `dirService.query` will do the `$resource` call and return the data, whether doing that `$resource` call from the controller wouldn't make more sense as that `$resource` need to write many times as you want..by defining `$resource` method in factory would make it reusable

Comment: Actually I believe the controllerAs syntax is getting more commonly used. Perhaps take a look into that.

Answer (score 0):

**It totally depends on situation**

```
$scope.phoneNumbers = dirService.query();
```

When you want to communicate between controllers then you can use this

```
$scope.getPhoneNumbers = function(){ ....//logic to get the data. }
```

When you need function inside a controller and it has no work to communicate with other controllers then you can use this.

**Best Practices always depends on scenarios**